# How to use Mat.ForEachAsDouble method in OpenCVsharp

Tags: c#, opencv, delegates, unsafe

I'm trying to evaluate the ForEachAs method in OpenCvsharp, but I'm not sure how to use the method.

I have loaded a gray scale image into a Mat type. I then try to use the ForEachAsInt16 method on this image. The ForEachAsInt16 metod takes a MatForeachFunctionInt16 operation as input. So I need to instantiate a function pointer (delegate) of this type. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `unsafe` named function with appropriate signature as `ForEachAsInt16()` argument in unsafe context and compile your project with `/unsafe` keyword.

Example of a function with appropriate signature:

```
unsafe static void Operation(short* pixel, int* position)
{
    // Get or set pixel value.
    short intencity = *pixel;
    var row = position[0];
    var col = position[1];
}
```

You can pass it as an argument:

```
unsafe
{
    mat.ForEachAsInt16(Operation);
}
```

For more information check:

- [cv::Mat::forEach()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d) OpenCV documentation
- [unsafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8(v=vs.71).aspx) reference on MSDN
- [/unsafe (C# Compiler Options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option) reference
- [Implimentation "cv::Mat::forEach" (revised)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/2639) pull request to OpenCV